# Nested object iterate and return empty value key name nodejs

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, lodash

I have an object like below

```
     var json = {
      "info": {
      "name": {},
      "addr": {
        "strreet": "NYC",
        "zip": 123456789
       }
     }
   }
```

I want to return the key where it has empty object, it may be nested for example in above json "name" is empty so I want to write a function and want to return "name" here

I have written a function for that given below

```
function iterate(obj) {
for (var property in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        if (typeof obj[property] == "object") {
            if (JSON.stringify(obj[property]) === '{}') {
                return property
            } else
                iterate(obj[property]);
        } else {}
    }
}
}
```

Now I'm calling this function like

```
var key = iterate(json)
console.log('Key',key)
```

Now key is printing undefined , any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep a blank array and keep on pushing the empty properties in it. In the last you will need to return this array for the recursion to work and where you are calling the function recursively you will need to push its content in the empty property array.

```js
var json = {
  "personInfo": {
    "personAttributesInfo": {
      "location": {
        "city": "New york",
        "state": {},
      }
    }
  },
  "dataInfo": {
    "travelPricing": {},
    "cost": {
      "usd": 12345,
      "someother": {},
    }
  }
};

function iterate(obj) {
  var emptyProperties = [];
  for (var property in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
      if (typeof obj[property] == "object") {
        if (Object.keys(obj[property]).length === 0) {
          emptyProperties.push(property);
        } else{
          let x = iterate(obj[property]);
          emptyProperties.push(...x);
        }
      } else {
        continue;
      }
    }
  }
  return emptyProperties;
}

var key = iterate(json)
console.log('Key', key);
```

Comment: Not working for this json var json = {
  
  "personInfo": {
    "personAttributesInfo": {
     
     
      "location": {
        "city": "New york"
        
      }
    }
  },
  "dataInfo": {
    "travelPricing": {
 
    },
    "cost": {
     "usd": 12345,    
    }
  }
}

Comment: @JohneDoe see the updated answer with an even more complicated object.

Comment: What is ` emptyProperties.push(...x);` and why we are using array , i need only first encounter empty object not all

Answer (score 1):

function `iterate` expects something. You have to return from `else`

```
return iterate(obj[property]);
```

```js
var json = {
      "info": {
      "name": {},
      "addr": {
        "strreet": "NYC",
        "zip": 123456789
       }
     }
   }


function iterate(obj) {
for (var property in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        if (typeof obj[property] == "object") {
            if (JSON.stringify(obj[property]) === '{}') {
                return property
            } else
                return iterate(obj[property]);
        } else {}
    }
}
}


var key = iterate(json)
console.log('Key', key)
```

Comment: This will not work for nested, for example check this json var json = {
  
  "personInfo": {
    "personAttributesInfo": {
     
     
      "location": {
        "city": "New york"
        
      }
    }
  },
  "dataInfo": {
    "travelPricing": {
 
    },
    "cost": {
     "usd": 12345,    
    }
  }
}

Comment: It's still returning undefined after code changes suggested by you

Comment: @JohneDoe, are getting `undefined` with the input in the comment?

Comment: Yes i'm getting input in the comment

Comment: It should return travelPricing

Answer (score 0):

This answer uses [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan).

As indicated as desired by the author in a comment, only the first encounter is returned.

*Observations:*

- `object-scan` will traverse into nested arrays. If that is not desired one could check `!Array.isArray(value)` in `breakFn`.
- If performance is important one could separate the compile and search part of `object-scan`

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const isEmptyObject = (value) => (
  value instanceof Object
  && !Array.isArray(value)
  && Object.keys(value).length === 0
);
const finder = (input) => objectScan(['**'], {
  abort: true,
  rtn: 'key',
  filterFn: ({ value }) => isEmptyObject(value)
})(input).pop();

const json = { personInfo: { personAttributesInfo: { location: { city: 'New york', state: {} } } }, dataInfo: { travelPricing: {}, cost: { usd: 12345, someother: {} } } };

console.log(finder(json));
// => someother
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@13.8.0"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)